# "no matching function for call to : " compiler error

Tags: c++

```
class Zbiornik
{
public:
    Zbiornik(int rozmiar)
    {
        int liczby[rozmiar];
    }
};
```

in code:

```
Zbiornik cyfry;
cyfry = liczby;
```

Can someone explain how to fix `main.cpp:67:10: error: no matching function for call to 'Zbiornik::Zbiornik()'` and why it's happening?

I can't figure out what am i missing, help much appreciated,

Comment: Which is line 67 and what is `liczby`?

Answer (score 4):

Since you defined a user-defined constructor, the implicit default constructor is not generated for you by the compiler. The idea is that it wouldn't do the right thing if it was implicitly generated since you have a user-defined ctor. Therefore, you have to define it yourself:

```
Zbiornik(){...}
```

However, you have mutiple problems `cyfry = liczby;` and `int liczby[rozmiar];` will not compile and I don't know what you are trying to do with those lines.

For one, `rozmiar` cannot be used in a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a default constructor (one that takes no parameters). You need to add:

`Zbiornik::Zbiornik()`, or alternatively, pass an integer through to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 Zbiornik cyfry;
```

calls the `Zbiornik()` constructor of your class.

But your class only has the `Zbiornik(int rozmiar)` constructor. And since you have defined a constructor, the compiler does not generate a default `Zbiornik()` constructor for you.

Add the constructor

```
Zbiornik() {}
```

to your class.